# How to trim a string inside a query string passed to the Pandas query function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to trim the 'My Pet' column inside the query string. How can that be done?

```
# Note that one cat literal has a trailing space.
testDF = pd.DataFrame([{"My Pet":"cat ",   "Cost":"$10 ", "Weight":"10 pounds", "Name":"Violet"},
                       {"My Pet":"cat",    "Cost":"$10 ", "Weight":"15 pounds", "Name":"Sirius"},
                       {"My Pet":"dog",    "Cost":"$0 ",  "Weight":"50 pounds", "Name":"Sam"},
                       {"My Pet":"turtle", "Cost":"$5 ",  "Weight":"20 ounces", "Name":"Tommy"},
                      ])
# We try to filter on cat. 
catDF = testDF.query("`My Pet` == 'cat'")  # This yields only one row because one cat cell has a trailing space
catDF.head()
```

Output is only one row but I would like to get both rows with cat in them

```
    My Pet  Cost    Weight  Name
1   cat     $10     15 pounds   Sirius
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), but need `engine="python"`:

```
catDF = testDF.query("`My Pet`.str.strip() == 'cat'", engine="python")
print (catDF)
  My Pet  Cost     Weight    Name
0   cat   $10   10 pounds  Violet
1    cat  $10   15 pounds  Sirius
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access string methods on string series. This means that you can use the [`Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) function to clean remove whitespace.

```py
testDF["My Pet"] = testDF["My Pet"].str.strip()
```

If you want to only clean trailing spaces then use `rstrip` (and `lstrip` for leading spaces)

You can optionally specify the set of characters you want to remove explicitly. E.g. to remove only spaces and tabs:

```py
testDF["My Pet"] = testDF["My Pet"].str.strip(" \t")
```